# Anti-earthquake stability of wall constructions derived from the physics of differently shaped bricks

Tags: forces, potential-energy, earth

I am interested if the proposed shape of bricks would have impact on stability of walls.I think the cube structure would not absorb so well the lever effect when a possible earthquake moves every upper brick left-right and tries to break the connection with the lower one.Should the variant b) from the picture reinforce stability due to more contact surface?Important..the b) variant is that shaped only in the dimension of wall tickness.In the width and height dimensions it has also a square shape like the a) variant of cubic brick....
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The keys to making unmortared & unreinforced block structures resistant to earthquake damage are to include interlocking features which hold adjacent blocks in good contact via gravity, to fit the blocks together with as much mating surface area as possible, and to tilt the walls inwards at an angle near to the angle of repose for the blocks themselves.

The interlocking features prevent the blocks from shifting out of alignment while being shaken in shear, as does the accurate fit- both of which tend to make the structure vibrate as a single unit. The depth of the interlocking features is chosen to prevent vertical shaking from disengaging the blocks from one another and the wall tilt resists the tendency of the structure to fall apart into individual blocks.